# java script load issue with ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, typescript

my javascript file for multiple email(multiple_emails.js plugin) is working fine with `ng serve`  my code  :

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.multiple_emails = function(options) {

        // Default options
        var defaults = {
            checkDupEmail: true,
            theme: "Bootstrap",
            position: "top",
            invalid:"Invalid Email Id"
        };

        // Merge send options with defaults
        var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        var deleteIconHTML = "";
        if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Bootstrap".toLowerCase())
        {
            deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>';
        }
        else if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "SemanticUI".toLowerCase() || settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Semantic-UI".toLowerCase() || settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Semantic UI".toLowerCase()) {
            deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><i class="remove icon"></i></a>';
        }
        else if (settings.theme.toLowerCase() == "Basic".toLowerCase()) {
            //Default which you should use if you don't use Bootstrap, SemanticUI, or other CSS frameworks
            deleteIconHTML = '<a href="#" class="multiple_emails-close" title="Remove"><i class="basicdeleteicon">Remove</i></a>';
        }

        return this.each(function() {
            var to_id = this.id;
            var orig_id=to_id;
            console.log(to_id);
            var arr = to_id.split('_');
            to_id = arr[1];
            console.log("to_id",to_id);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log($('.licls'+to_id).length);
                if($('.licls'+to_id).length > 4){
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','none');
                }else {
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','block');
                }
                },200);

            //$orig refers to the input HTML node
            var $orig = $(this);
            var $list = $('<ul class="multiple_emails-ul" id=ul_'+to_id+' />'); // create html elements - list of email addresses as unordered list
            console.log($(this).val());
            if ($(this).val() != '' && IsJsonString($(this).val())) {
                $.each(jQuery.parseJSON($(this).val()), function( index, val ) {
                    $list.append($('<li class="multiple_emails-email licls'+to_id+'"><span class="email_name" data-email="' + val.toLowerCase() + '">' + val + '</span></li>')
                      .prepend($(deleteIconHTML)
                           .click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); refresh_emails(); e.preventDefault(); })
                      )
                    );
                });
            }

            var $input = $('<input type="text" class="multiple_emails-input text-left" id= input_'+to_id+' />').on('keyup', function(e) { // input              
                console.log($(this).attr('id'));
                $(this).removeClass('multiple_emails-error');
                $('#'+orig_id).parent().find("label").remove();
                var input_length = $(this).val().length;
                var keynum;
                if(window.event){ // IE                 
                    keynum = e.keyCode;
                }
                else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                 
                    keynum = e.which;
                }

                //if(event.which == 8 && input_length == 0) { $list.find('li').last().remove(); } //Removes last item on backspace with no input

                // Supported key press is tab, enter, space or comma, there is no support for semi-colon since the keyCode differs in various browsers
                if(keynum == 9 || keynum == 32 || keynum == 188) { 
                    display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail);
                }
                else if (keynum == 13) {
                if($('.licls'+to_id).length > 4){
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','none');
                }else {
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','block');
                }
                    display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail);
                    //Prevents enter key default
                    //This is to prevent the form from submitting with  the submit button
                    //when you press enter in the email textbox
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

            }).on('blur', function(event){ 
                if($('.licls'+to_id).length > 4){
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','none');
                }else {
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','block');
                }
                $('#'+orig_id).parent().find("label").remove();
                if ($(this).val() != '') { display_email($(this), settings.checkDupEmail); }
            });

            var $container = $('<div class="multiple_emails-container contnr_'+to_id+'" />').click(function() { $input.focus(); } ); // container div

            // insert elements into DOM
            if (settings.position.toLowerCase() === "top")
                $container.append($list).append($input).insertAfter($(this));
            else
                $container.append($input).append($list).insertBefore($(this));

            /*
            t is the text input device.
            Value of the input could be a long line of copy-pasted emails, not just a single email.
            As such, the string is tokenized, with each token validated individually.

            If the dupEmailCheck variable is set to true, scans for duplicate emails, and invalidates input if found.
            Otherwise allows emails to have duplicated values if false.
            */
            function display_email(t, dupEmailCheck) {
                console.log(t.attr('id'));
                //Remove space, comma and semi-colon from beginning and end of string
                //Does not remove inside the string as the email will need to be tokenized using space, comma and semi-colon
                var arr = t.val().trim().replace(/^,|,$/g , '').replace(/^;|;$/g , '');
                //Remove the double quote
                arr = arr.replace(/"/g,"");
                //Split the string into an array, with the space, comma, and semi-colon as the separator
                arr = arr.split(/[\s,;]+/);

                var errorEmails = new Array(); //New array to contain the errors

                var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);

                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    var res_arr=JSON.parse($orig.val().toLowerCase().split(','))
                    //Check if the email is already added, only if dupEmailCheck is set to true
                    if ( dupEmailCheck === true && res_arr.indexOf(arr[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        if (arr[i] && arr[i].length > 0) {
                            new function () {
                                var existingElement = $list.find('.email_name[data-email=' + arr[i].toLowerCase().replace('.', '\\.').replace('@', '\\@') + ']');
                                existingElement.css('font-weight', 'bold');
                                setTimeout(function() { existingElement.css('font-weight', ''); }, 1500);
                            }(); // Use a IIFE function to create a new scope so existingElement won't be overriden
                        }
                    }
                    else if ( pattern.test(arr[i]) == true && res_arr.indexOf(arr[i].toLowerCase()) == -1) {                        
                        if($('#ulcls'+t.attr('id')).length < 4) {
                            $list.append($('<li class="multiple_emails-email licls'+to_id+'"><span class="email_name" data-email="' + arr[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + arr[i] + '</span></li>')
                              .prepend($(deleteIconHTML)
                                   .click(function(e) { $(this).parent().remove(); refresh_emails(); e.preventDefault(); })
                              )
                        );
                        }                       
                    }
                    else
                        errorEmails.push(arr[i]);
                }
                // If erroneous emails found, or if duplicate email found
                if(errorEmails.length > 0) {
                    t.val(errorEmails.join("; ")).addClass('multiple_emails-error');

                    t.after('<label for='+orig_id+' style="color:#cc5965;">'+settings.invalid+'</label>');
                }else {
                $('#'+orig_id).parent().find("label").remove();
                    t.val("");
                }
                refresh_emails ();
            }

            function refresh_emails () {                
                var emails = new Array();
                var container = $orig.siblings('.multiple_emails-container');
                container.find('.multiple_emails-email span.email_name').each(function() { emails.push($(this).html()); });
                $orig.val(JSON.stringify(emails)).trigger('change');
                if($('.licls'+to_id).length > 4){
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','none');
                }else {
                    $('#input_'+to_id).css('display','block');
                }
            }

            function IsJsonString(str) {
                try { JSON.parse(str); }
                catch (e) { return false; }
                return true;
            }
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#input_'+to_id).on("cut copy paste",function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                     });
});
            return $(this).hide();

        });

    };

})(jQuery);
```

But when i compile it with `ng build --prod` it's gives TypeError: $(...).multiple_emails is not a function , if it's not working correctly any other tool to convert from JavaScript to typescript ?

i had convert js into typesript using online compiler but nothing happened.

Comment: Make sure sequence of script is correct

Comment: in angular-cli.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved!!!!
finally i figure out the problem. it is in angular-cli.json.when i place my multiple_email.js after jquery-3.1.1.min.js,jquery.validate.min.js then it works like charm...!!! @rajesh thanks